# Does anybody know the default Exception codes for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, exception

Does anybody know the default Exception codes for PHP? Mainly for database exceptions.

I know that:

```
42000 is a sql syntax error
23000 is duplicate unique key entry
```

What other exception codes are there that I should know about?

Comment: Those are MySQL error codes, not PHP errors. PHP may return them if a query goes wrong, but it's just telling you what MySQL said. See the link in Daan's answer for a listing of codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "default exception codes for PHP", but it looks as if you're looking for the explanation of MySQL error codes, which you can find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) :)

Comment: That'll be why I couldn't find any explanation in the PHP docs then! I basically want to know what exceptions could be thrown so I can handle them correctly, so that's perfect, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you might want to look into [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

mysql_select_db("nonexistentdb", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";

mysql_select_db("kossu", $link);
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonexistenttable", $link);
echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n"; # <- text message
?>
```